# ToHashSet of a ToAsynchList and keeping the asynchrone behavior

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The end goal here is to get a list of distincts objects.

```
_items = (await _itemRepository.GetItems()
                               .Select(x => new ThiShinnyLocalObject
                                           {
                                               Id = x.Id,
                                           }).ToListAsync()).ToHashSet();
```

My question is the following. Since `ToHashSet` have no asychrone method and the method that this code is in need to be a `Task`. Is there a better way to write the query and keeping that asynchrone behavior?

Comment: You can include a `Distinct` in your db query; then the resulting list would have distinct elements.

Comment: I tough of the same, but I was hopping to avoid changing the `ISet` nature of the result.